# Origins of drain flies in apt?

Tags: plumbing

We live in an upscale relatively small and new building in suburbs of NY. It’s a 2bdrm. I and my husband keep it exceptionally clean —trash taken out near daily, sweeping-mopping-vacuuming done every other day, no food is ever left out, no dishes ever left in sink but placed into dishwasher immediately, any spills taken care of, etc.

Despite all this, for the last 2 months, we have had about 3 dozen flies hover above each of our three sinks (kitchen+each of two bathrooms)

Building pest control has come by and treated sinks and surrounding area last Tue by pouring pesticides down the drains. No improvements. Above each sink there is a constant swarm of flies. Pest control said they will treat once a week until the problem is resolved.

My husband and I are wondering: are the pest control people diagnosing and treating the problem correctly? What could be causing this?

Comment: Correlation =/= causation. The flies are near the drains because that's where the most tasty odor (and water) can be found. They're probably not entering there.

Comment: I'm also not sure I'd agree to pesticides being poured into my municipal drinking water system.

Comment: Are these big black house flies or small little gnat-like flies?

Comment: Small, gnat-like flies

Answer (score 2):

Check your houseplants. It sounds like they are gnats that live in overly moist soil. Look for fungus in the soil and if you find them, decrease watering and treat with a solution of neem oil to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Drain flies are a real thing. They breed inside the (usually shower) drain and hang around their nursery. They can be eradicated with persistence and lots of Raid sprayed into and around the drains after each use. Don't be too surprised if they return in a few weeks or months.

Comment: Yeah, could be. 
Dump a pot of boiling water down the drawn twice a day for a week, then to keep drain flies away, pour 1/2 cup of baking soda down the drain and flush it with warm water once a week.